# why 'abc'.indexOf([]) === 0?

Tags: javascript

I'm try to get an string index of another value

```
let index = 'any string'.indexOf([]);
console.log(index); // 0
```

Why the index value is `0`?

Comment: Every string contains the empty string. Just like an empty set is a subset of every set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.prototype.indexOf` converts any object, given as a search pattern, to a string.

String representation of `[]` is `''` (empty string).
If you apply `indexOf('')` to any string, it will return 0.

```js
console.log([].toString());

console.log('qwerty'.indexOf([])); // this one gives the same result
console.log('qwerty'.indexOf('')); // as this one

console.log(['a', 1].toString());

console.log('gfdsa,12345'.indexOf(['a', 1])); // these two give 
console.log('gfdsa,12345'.indexOf('a,1')); // the same result as well
```